# catel type registration hangs in parallel unit tests

Tags: catel

I have switched to Catel for IoC a while ago, but when I want to run my unit tests in parallel, I get deadlocks in GetTypesEx from deep within catel.

The stack trace looks like this:

> Catel.Core.dll!Catel.Reflection.ReflectionExtensions.GetTypesEx(System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) Line 40    C#
>       Catel.Core.dll!Catel.Reflection.AssemblyHelper.GetAllTypesSafely(System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, bool logLoaderExceptions) Line 155    C#
>       Catel.Core.dll!Catel.Reflection.TypeCache.GetAssemblyTypes.AnonymousMethod__42_1(System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) Line 829  C#
>       System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator>>.MoveNext() Unknown
>       System.Core.dll!System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToDictionary>, System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery>> source, System.Func>, System.Reflection.Assembly> keySelector, System.Func>, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet> elementSelector, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer comparer)    Unknown
>       Catel.Core.dll!Catel.Reflection.TypeCache.GetAssemblyTypes(System.Collections.Generic.List assemblies, bool allowMultithreadedInitialization) Line 836  C#
>       Catel.Core.dll!Catel.Reflection.TypeCache.InitializeAssemblies(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable assemblies, bool force, bool allowMultithreadedInitialization) Line 711   C#
>       Catel.Core.dll!Catel.Reflection.TypeCache.InitializeTypes(System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, bool forceFullInitialization, bool allowMultithreadedInitialization) Line 674    C#
>       Catel.Core.dll!Catel.Reflection.TypeCache.TypeCache() Line 113  C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       Catel.Core.dll!Catel.HttpContextHelper.GetHttpContext() Line 26 C#
>       Catel.Core.dll!Catel.Core.ModuleInitializer.GetExeConfiguration() Line 80   C#
>       Catel.Core.dll!Catel.Core.ModuleInitializer.Initialize() Line 41    C#
>       Catel.Core.dll!.()  Unknown
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       PluginTests.dll!PluginTests.AcquisitionPlugin.InitServiceManager(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext context) Line 103 C#

Any idea how I could avoid this?
I am not aware of doing anything fundamentally wrong. I am registering my types in the class initialization methods (using MStest 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to initialize the TypeCache on forehand:

```
TypeCache.InitializeTypes(allowMultithreadedInitialization: false);
```

But even better: report a ticket (preferrably with repro!) so the Catel team can fix this.

Comment: Could not yet strip it down for a test project, but the issue is this one: https://github.com/Catel/Catel/issues/1244 - thank you for the quick help!